# MVC confusion (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Using CodeIgniter, or any MVC framework, provided that the **Model** is the database wrapper and **Controller** must not contain any information about database or any connection with database.

Now, if a person create a generic Model class say "**DB_Model**" with a method

```
add($table, $fields)
```

To use this method, that person must call it from a **Controller** as

```
$this->DB_Model->add('my_table_name', $fields)
```

Now, the question is, isn't this wrong by the definition of a **Model-View-Controller** framework? I mean, the Controller now got information about the database.

Thanks

EDIT: I am not questioning CI but just the above practice that some people do to spend less time on applications, coding.

Comment: But isn't it the model doing the actual database work?

Comment: $db_model_obj = new DB_Model();

Comment: $db_model_obj->someFunction();

Comment: $this->render('some_view',array('some_key'=>$db_model_obj));

Comment: You don't create a method in the Model layer that requires the table name. If you're taking Orders, the method should be `create_order($some_post_fields_array)`. The Controller calls `$result = $this->BI_model->create_order($post_data);`. You don't even have to use the letters DB anywhere.

Comment: [You can also keep all the form validation rules out of the controller](http://avenir.ro/validation-rules-inside-the-model-codeigniter/) if you wanted.

Comment: @qwertzman I know but information did leak out. Controller now has the class name which one can argue that it should (only) be part of Model.

Comment: The goal of MVC is to decouple the various components of an application. What definition of the MVC framework does CI fail against?

Comment: @qwertzman No one said CI is the issue or it fail agains MVC definition but its merely the person who tries to implement it the way I explained in my question. I am only question the *PRACTICE* that I laid down in my question.

Comment: "isn't this wrong by the definition of a Model-View-Controller framework?" "Yes." Now, what are you going to do with that answer? Do you have an actual example where someone is saying this is the right way to do things? Are you trying to decide how you should write something? I'm struggling to see what answer you're expecting here.

Comment: @IMSoP Of course, I am expecting the right answer, if its a Yes or a No. Actually, it was a debate with a senior developer than me and the agression he showed while defending that it won't break MVC had me doubt maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way CI works is

create a method in the model where the actual DB work is done.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

create a controller that calls the model:

```
class Blog_controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function blog()
        {
                $this->load->model('blog');
                $data['query'] = $this->blog->get_last_ten_entries();
                $this->load->view('blog', $data);
        }
}
```

example taken from link above.

edit: yeah it's wrong in my opinion, it's not correctly decoupled the way they told you (?).

Comment: I would call CI MVC-ish. One of there selling points is: _CodeIgniter encourages MVC, but does not force it on you._